# Simplest way to grab camera images from Java

Tags: camera, opencv, java

I want to write a software that runs on the JVM (in Scala but you can think Java). I am looking for the simplest way to capture images from the standard camera module (v2). I find the `raspstill` quite clunky, slow, somewhat unpredictable with respect to exact exposure times, glitches etc., and I would like to avoid writing files (I process a batch of images in memory before writing out averaged pictures), so if there is a direct API I would prefer it.

For example, [here](http://stefanshacks.blogspot.co.at/2015/05/build-opencv-with-java-bindings-on_6.html) is a tutorial on getting the Java bindings for OpenCV to work with the RaspPi camera. Are there better or more simple options (also considering the build time and disk space required for OpenCV)?

Comment: I found a [Java project on GitHub](https://github.com/Hopding/JRPiCam), but it still goes through `raspstill`.